# OpenLayers Circle not visible

Tags: openlayers-2, spherical-geometry, circle

I'm trying to draw a circle with OpenLayers with a Google Maps Layer. I'm able to transform a simple marker and have it draw at the correct location, but I can't figure out the circle. I'm trying to draw a 50 meter radius circle:

```
function InitializeMap() {

// create map
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map_canvas",
    theme: null,
    units:'m', 
    projection: "EPSG:900913",
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        })
    ]
});

// load layers
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
    "Road", // the default
    {numZoomLevels: 20}
);
map.addLayer(gmap);
if (map.layers.length > 0) {
    var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Terrain",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}
    );
    map.addLayer(gphy);
    var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Hybrid",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20}
    );
    map.addLayer(ghyb);
    var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Satellite",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
    );
    map.addLayer(gsat);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher);
}
var blankmap = new OpenLayers.Layer("Blank", {
    isBaseLayer: true,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
        -128 * 156543.03390625,
        -128 * 156543.03390625,
        128 * 156543.03390625,
        128 * 156543.03390625
    ),
    sphericalMercator: true,
    maxResolution: 156543.03390625,
    units: "m",
    projection: "EPSG:900913"});
map.addLayer(blankmap);

// Set default layer if not offline
if (map.layers.length > 1) {
  switch (default_map_type) {
    case 1: map.setBaseLayer(blankmap); break;  
    case 2: map.setBaseLayer(gmap); break;
    case 3: map.setBaseLayer(gsat); break;
    case 4: map.setBaseLayer(ghyb); break;
    case 5: map.setBaseLayer(gphy); break; 
  }
}

// Add Layers to map
    var currentLocationLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Current Location");
    var currentAccuracyLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Current Accuracy");
    map.addLayer(currentLocationLayer);
map.addLayer(currentAccuracyLayer);

    // Add marker
    var current_point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-81,37.transform(map.displayProjection,map.getProjectionObject());
    map.setCenter(current_point);
    map.zoomTo(17);
    current_loc_marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(current_point,image_GPS);
    currentLocationLayer.addMarker(current_loc_marker);

    // Add circle
    var hA_circle_geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(current_point, 50, 50, 0).transform(map.displayProjection,map.getProjectionObject());
    hA_circle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(hA_circle_geometry);
currentAccuracyLayer.addFeatures([hA_circle]);
}
```

I tried the following for the circle and it still does nto show. Does it need to be transformed due to the Google Layer?:

```
var hA_circle = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(currentAccuracyLayer,
                                        OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon,
                                        {sides: 40, radius: 50, angle: 0});
map.addControl(hA_circle);
```

Comment: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/regular-polygons.html [Draw Polygon on] Shape=circle view source

Comment: Thanks, I still can't get it to work. I added the code to the post above. Does the feature need to be transformed due to the Google Projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe current_point should be OpenLayers.Geometry.Point instead of OpenLayers.LonLat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add a circle to a Google Satellite Layer:

```
var current_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(current_location[0].longitude,current_location[0].latitude).transform(map.displayProjection,map.getProjectionObject());
var hA_circle_geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(current_point, 50, 50, 0);
hA_circle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(hA_circle_geometry);
currentAccuracyLayer.addFeatures([hA_circle]);
```